# Confusion about average force applied over a time interval

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

If I understand correctly, the word average implies the average of forces acting during a certain time.

$$F_{avg}=\frac{\int_{t_i}^{t_f}{F(t)\,dt}}{t_f-t_i}$$

The teacher gave us tasks with answers to prepare for tomorrow test from his book.  Here is one of them:

> 3. A pellet gun fires 10 pellets of 2.0 g, per second with a speed of 500 m/s.  The pellets are
>      stopped by a rigid wall. What are
>
> a)  the magnitude of the linear momentum of each pellet?
>
> b)  the kinetic energy of each pellet?
>
> c)  **the magnitude of the average force on the wall from the stream of the pellets?**
>
> d)  **If each  pellet is  in contact  with the  wall for  0.55 ms,  what  is  the  magnitude  of  the
>   average force on the wall from each pellet during contact?**
>
> e)  **Why these two average forces calculated here are so different?**

Answer:

> a) Linear momentum of each pellet
>   $$p=mv=0.002*500=1kg*m/s$$
>   b) Kinetic energy of each pellet is
>   $$W=0.5*0.002*500=0.5J$$
>   c) Ten pellets are stuck into the wall in a second,  so the average force is
>   $$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=\frac{10*1}{1}=10N$$ d) The force during the contact is
>   $$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=\frac{1}{0.00055}=1820N$$e) The difference is due of the long (0.1 s) delay between the bullets

I think, there's a typo in b. $K=\frac{mv^2}{2}=0.002*500^2*0.5=250J$

$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}{F(t)\,dt}$ is all force exerted on wall by pellets. By third Newton's law it equals to all force, the wall exerted on pellets.

$|\int_{t_i}^{t_f}{F(t)\,dt}|=m_p|\int_{t_i}^{t_f} a(t) \, dt|=|m_{p}(v_{p_i}-v_{p_f})|=|\Delta p|$

I think that $v_{p_i}=-v_{p_f}$ because nothing is said about energy loss.

Then, under (If $F_{avg}$ is calculated per second) c): $|F|=\frac{10|F_p|}{1}=\frac{10*0.002*2*500}{1}=20N$

Conditions under d imply that $t_f-t_i=0.00055$

It does not affect $\Delta p$

Then, previous answer can be divided by 10 (to calculate result for one pellet) and by 0.00055
 Answer is 3640N

Then, under e delay between shots can't affect the result. It changed because we changed $\Delta t$ we consider

Comment: Yes to the typo in b) $W=\frac{1}{2} m v^2$

Comment: Note that the problem statement says that the pellets "are stopped by a rigid wall".  So $v_f = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c) the magnitude of the average force on the wall from the stream of
>   the pellets?

It should be 
$$
\begin{align}
\text{average force} \times \text{total time} &= \text{total change in momentum}\\
F_{ave} \times (1\, \mathrm{s}) &= 10 \times (1 \,\mathrm{kg\, m/s}) 
\end{align}
$$
So $F_{ave}=10 \,\mathrm{N}$, in agreement with your instructor's answer.

> d) If each pellet is in contact with the wall for 0.55 ms, what is the
>   magnitude of the average force on the wall from each pellet during
>   contact?

Each impact has 
$$
F\times(0.00055 \,\mathrm{s}) = (1 \,\mathrm{kg\, m/s})
$$
So $F = 1818.2 \,\mathrm{N}$, in agreement with your instructor's answer.

The average force is explained as a *constant force* applied over the total time that results in the same change in momentum as all the individual varying forces.

Comment: to be clear, you agree with the quoted answers.

Comment: Well b) is wrong (obviously) and I disagree with c). The instructor has F=10 and I have F=1

Comment: @ja oops that was careless of me.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I don't like $\times$ for multiplication because I used it as cross product often. And $*$ is clunky, so that leaves $\cdot$ or nothing for implicit multiplication.

Comment: but having re-read the question, the instructor's c) is correct - 10 bullets are fired per second - the total time is 1 second.

Comment: ah ok, of course feel free to revert the edits

Comment: 10 bullets, at each second (per second) equals 10 seconds. It is clear to me.

Comment: no! it's 10 bullets per second, not 10 bullets, 1 per second!

Comment: Can we agree that the total time is 10 seconds?

Comment: No, the total time is one second, during which 10 bullets are fired.

Comment: Oh, I edited the answer then.

Comment: I didn't understand what is meant by `stopped`. I see.

Comment: If a pellet bounces off then the total momentum change is _double_ of what it is if the pellet stops.