# What is the time period which we refer to when we say the average force is the impulse over change in time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

> a pellet gun fires ten 2.14-g pellets per second with a speed of 483 m/s. The pellet is stopped by a rigid wall. Calculate average force exerted by stream of pellets on the wall?

So, in the solution key for this question, they do

$$ F_{avg} \cdot 1 = 2.14 \cdot 483 \cdot 10^{-3} $$

But, I'm confused why one second is taken..? What exactly is the time period which we take for impulse? do we take the time period over which the collision happens or the time period for which new momentum is introduced into our system?

[Confusion about average force applied over a time interval](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175155/confusion-about-average-force-applied-over-a-time-interval)

I saw this post which is almost the same question but they don't address my problem

In the textbook of resnick halliday, they write,

> To find the total change in momentum during the entire collision, we integrate over the time of collision, starting at time $t_i$ ( when the momementum is $\vec{p_i})$ and ending at time $t_f$ (when the momentum is $\vec{p_f}$

(page -122) but I'm not so sure after this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they are assuming one bullet is stopped over a time of one second, although this isn't stated in what you have quoted. I'm not sure how they are wanting you to take into account the entire stream though (maybe they are thinking each bullet is stopped in $0.1$ seconds?). It looks like this is a poorly worded question.

In general, the average force $F_\text{avg}$ is just related to the change in momentum $\Delta p$ over some time interval $\Delta t$ such that
$$F_\text{avg}=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$

So really your question is analogous to, "What is the time period which we refer to when we say the average velocity is the displacement over change in time?". It is whatever time period you are considering for the change in momentum in your case or for the change in displacement in the above example.